# Is there any way to give onclick attribute to each loop element in which we call different function for different element

Tags: html, pug, calculator

I wanna make my pug Attributes like the HTML code but PUG elements are in looop

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/imbharat420/pen/bGVGJmV)

[image: Code in pug]

```html
html
 head
   title
 body
  .container
    input#result(type="text" class="output div1")
    -const btn = ['button'] 
    -const list= ['C','±','<','&divide;','7','8','9','&times;','4','5','6','&dash;','1','2','3','+','0','.','=']
    each val in list
     -const attr ={type:"button",value:val}
      input.div2(class=btn)&attributes(attr)
```

[image: Code in HTML]

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of images.

Comment: @Graham i already uploaded the Pug codes 
and HTML codes are this Please check
https://codepen.io/codingandstuff/pen/XWbNBPL

Comment: It's not just me, it's a rule on the site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Also note that code uploaded to codepen doesn't count either, you need to show it here so future users can see what was wrong.